# How to use async values from an actor in a Text View in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, async-await, actor

I am using xcode 13.3 beta 3 and trying to modify my app to use actors. Since all of my variables are now in an actor(s) so they cannot be accessed directly, how do I use these async values in a Text View? I found one possible solution from the last post for the following link:  [How can I use async/await with SwiftUI in Swift 5.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67375031/how-can-i-use-async-await-with-swiftui-in-swift-5-5). This was the only way I could find to use an async value in a Text View. The problem with this approach is that by using @State variable, I am required to pass those values in....which I can't do...Any ideas?

```
struct Forecast: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var ws: Webservice
    
    @State var forecast1tempMin = 0


               ....

    VStack {

    Text("\(forecast1tempMin)")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .task {
            forecast1tempMin = await ws.forecastActor.getForecast1TempMin()
        }

actor Forecast_Actor {
    @Published var forecast1_tempmin = 0
    
    func setForecast1TempMin(val: Int) async {
        
        forecast1_tempmin = val
    }
    
    func getForecast1TempMin() async -> Int {
        
        return forecast1_tempmin
    }
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = "Loading"

      // Async function
      func asyncGetText() async -> String {
          try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)
          return "My text"
      }
      
      var body: some View {
          Text(text)
          .task {
               text = await asyncGetText()
          }
      }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by: "The problem with this approach is that by using @State variable, I am required to pass those values in....which I can't do" You should avoid passing values to `@State` variables. Can you produce  a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your whole problem?

Comment: The issue is that I  cannot use async values in a Text View. The only solution I found was to use the Task {} construct to make the async call and place the result in a local variable (aka State variable) to assign to the Text View. So the State variable was the solution I found but it requires you to pass in those value, which did NOT want to do. Let me see if I can come up with an MRE as you say.. The million dollar question is how to use async values in a Text("\()") view. Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue with passing values in to a view? That is a standard MVVM concept. How else would you like the view to have access to the data?

Comment: I added an MRE below previous code. This code does want I want to be able to do as in Text(text) where text is result from async call. I do not want to wrap all of my async calls as asyncGetText() does.

Comment: by the way, the data I am displaying is @Published values that change over time......not something you can pass in...

Answer (score -1):

The original example of how to do this came from @malhal here on stackoverflow. I changed things around a bit to suit my needs. The original issue was how to pass into a swiftui Text() view an async value from an async call. I was trying to pass in an Int and needed to make it a String.

The following solved my problem. Thanks!

```
@State var forecast1tempMin: String
          ....
var body: some View {
        Text(forecast1tempMin)
           .foregroundColor(.white)
           .task {
                   forecast1tempMin = String(await ws.forecastActor.getForecast1TempMin())
           }
```

Comment: This solution still has the side affect of passing in noop data for the @State variables. As I don't need any actual values passed in, I need a place holder to pass the async data to the Text view...still working on that.

Comment: A little late, but change your first line to be:

```@State private var forecast1tempMin = ""```